# Method names too long in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA. I am using normalized DB which means, to get a full details of what i want, i have to join many tables. As you know JPA generates method name based on query. But, due to multiple joins, my method name becomes so long. sometimes, its more than 250 chars. 
I am looking for @query annotation with JPA methods instead of auto generated JPA method names.
I wanna know the performance implications if i use @query annotation?
Also, please suggest any alternatives to solve my long method names keeping performance into consideration.

Comment: I'm not sure about performance but query annotation is right way

Comment: Whatever time is spent parsing the query is minimal compared to actually running the query, so performance is not an issue you need to care about. Making sure the database has the right indexes for a good access plan is far more important.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you write your query using Spring Data (i.e `List<MyObj> findAllByName(String name)`) spring data actually generates your query the same way as you'd write it using `@Query` annotation. So, technically speaking, boot-up time will be quicker if you write your queries as `HQL` or `JPQL` within `@Query` annotation. The most performant way is of course to use native queries, but it can be a pain in the ass later in the game.

Comment: May i know why is it a pain later in the game? Can you please share me some examples or experience so that i can understand.

Comment: Let's say you want to migrate from one version of Postgres to another. In this case, you will have to manually adjust all your queries. In case if you `JPQL`/`HQL` your queries are built according to a driver version you are using. It is even worse if you are migrating from MySQL to PostgreSQL or Oracle.